# How to get all values of column A corresponding to certain value of column B in a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

The follow is my data.

```
,x
1,16239.2037182035
2,2290.58697355612
3,26661.4009577282
5,3404.57199108078
6,2017.05432741796
7,1281.6543596914
13,4856.59473014722
17,1108.97190826966
18,5292.00866901003
```

`data<-read.csv("test.csv",header=TRUE)`

```
data

        X            x
1       1 1.623920e+04
2       2 2.290587e+03
3       3 2.666140e+04
4       5 3.404572e+03
5       6 2.017054e+03
6       7 1.281654e+03
7      13 4.856595e+03
8      17 1.108972e+03
9      18 5.292009e+03
```

Now I want to get the x value when X=13, how to implement this?
I know that data[7,]$x can get the x value. But I want to get the x value when X is a certain value. 
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should do some research yourself before asking the community here. The answer to your question is in every manual on R: `data$x[data$X == 13]`

Comment: I am ashamed for asking this question. I know this is the basic knowledge. I googled this question but did not find the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO!. No need to be ashamed @Ben, everyone needs to start somewhere, we all did :). It is just that reading some tutorials about R would probably have found you your answer. Keeping SO clean with good questions also means keeping low quality answers to a minimum. But please keep asking questions, just be sure to do some research first. It would also help for your next question to include what kind of research you did (e.g. I googled for this and that).

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement. @Paul Hiemstra

Comment: @Ben don't be ashamed and welcome to SO!! You provided a reproducible example for your question and showed what you tried to do. This is a good format for your future questions (of which I hope there will be many!), just try to be a bit more patient when it comes to prior research in the future.

Comment: Ben, if you google the same way as your title here (*How to get certain value*), you'd not get much. You'll have to be more specific: "subsetting a data.frame R" (or) "extracting rows from a data.frame R" etc.. Also search on SO as well before asking a question.

Comment: @Ben for these kinds of basic questions, SO is not really a good place. For that, a course, or a on-to-one discussion with someone (e.g. an experienced colleague or teacher) works much better.

Comment: @Ben don't be ashamed. I know it can be difficult initially because R users come from various, diverse fields and there are many ways of doing same operation. Atleast now you know how to avoid `$` :-)

Comment: SimonO101, Arun, Paul Hiemstra, e4e5f4 You are so kind. I really appreciate your reply. Thank you.

Comment: @Ben My apologies if my comment sounded harsh, if your initial search did not deliver any results, asking a question on SO is a valid next step.

Comment: @Maxim.K I think the reason I didn't find the answer is that I didn't use the proper words to search just as Arun said. Thank you again. I learned a lot from this question. SO is a great forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of `?data.frame`, `?with`

```
with(df, x[X==13])
## [1] 4856.595
```

Also look into some introductory R tutorial on data frame indexing using logical vectors.